# Array of item in Java

Tags: arrays, class, sorting, arraylist, binary

Create an array that contains Item objects with the serial numbers, names and
unit prices.

o Allow a user to enter the serial number of an Item and print all the details of the
Item if it is in the array, otherwise state that the Item is not found.

This is the method:
It have an object class for it as well.

public static int binarySearchSerialNumber(Item[] a, int n){
        int mid;

```
    int first = 0;
    int last = a.length - 1;

    while (first <= last){

        mid = (first + last)/2;
        if (a[mid].getSerialNumber() == n)
            return mid;


        if (a[mid].getSerialNumber() > n)
            last = mid - 1;
        else
            first = mid + 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

The main: I'm trying to call back the method.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Item [] Numbers = new Item[5];
    Numbers[0]= new Item(1234, "Saw", 153.75);
    Numbers[1]= new Item(9876, "Hammer", 47.50);
    Numbers[2]= new Item(6432, "Drill", 272.99);
    Numbers[3]= new Item(4682, "I-Beam Level", 240.00);
    Numbers[4]= new Item(2090, "Shovel", 75.00);

    //Allowing user to enter serial number
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the Serial Number:");
    int serialN= s.nextInt();

    int sort= binarySearchSerialNumber(Numbers,serialN);
    System.out.println(sort);
```

Can someone advice me what to do, do i need to creat an if, else?

Answer (score 0):

Your method `binarySearchSerialNumber(Item[] a, int n)` is returning the index of array, so the condition should be if the data is found i.e `sort!=-1` it means the object is found, you will get the index of object in your `sort` variable, which you can output the result by using `.toString()`

```
int sort= binarySearchSerialNumber(Numbers,serialN);
if(sort!=-1)
System.out.println(Numbers[sort].toString());
```

Comment: I executed it.. but i'm getting a weird output --> Item@7d417077

Comment: You have to create your toString() method in your Numbers class. To do that you have to right click in your Numbers class then goto Source -> Generate toString()

Comment: My instructor was given instructions not to edit the Numbers class.

Comment: public class Item {

 private int serialNumber;
 private String name;
 private double unitPrice;

 public Item(int sn, String n, double p) {
  serialNumber = sn;
  name = n;
  unitPrice = p;
 }

 public int getSerialNumber(){
  return serialNumber;
 }

 public String getName(){
  return name;
 }

 public double getUnitPrice(){
  return unitPrice;
 }

 public void printDetails(){
  System.out.print("NAME: " + name);
  System.out.print(" || SERIAL NUMBER: " + serialNumber);
  System.out.println(" || UNIT PRICE: $" + unitPrice);
 }
}

Comment: Basically Item@7d417077 is the address of your object, in order to print its content you have to use toString() method if you cant edit your class you can print like System.out.println(Numbers[sort].getName() + Numbers[sort].getUnitPrice()); as many attributes you want to print of your object

Comment: so far.. it is only reading the first array which is Numbers[0]

Comment: It will read whatever your binarySearchSerialNumber algorithm returns as index